# jQuery Rotate Image Issues in IE7, IE8 and IE9

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, dom, rotation

I'm using this jQuery Rotate Plugin here:

http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/

The plugin is supposed to rotate images flawlessly in IE7, IE8, IE9 etc.. And I can rotate images without any problems:

http://jsfiddle.net/zmpdS/101/

However, I'm facing problems to chain two functions `.rotate()` (provided by the plugin) and `.animate()` (provided in jQuery core)

The problem is that `jQuery Rotate` plugin listed above uses `RVML` to rotate images in IE8 and IE7 whereas in other browsers it's CSS3 Rotations. So, for `RVML` the DOM is manipulated and the new `RVML` tags doesn't support `.animate()` function.

Is there a way out?

```
 $(window).load(function() {

     $("#test").rotate({
         angle: 0,
         animateTo: -90,
         duration: 2000,
         easing: $.easing.EaseOutQuint
     }).animate({
         height: "128px",
         width: "128px"
     }, 1000);

 });
```

Comment: No comments Jasdeep....That was what you needed right...Please accept if it helped

Comment: I'm not sure that this is going to be possible. Have you considered just leaving IE7/IE8 behind; giving them the rotate but not the animation?

Comment: People have got to stop trying to give older browsers (IE7 is definitely out of the question, IE8 should be too) "flashy effects". The JS and rendering engines of these browsers are so slow that it degrades the entire UX, not only that of the effect. This is precisely what Modernizr was created for.

Comment: @Adam - 2 years ago when I posted this question IE7 and 8 both had a very decent adoption with IE9 being the hot new thing. I finally went with just going ahead with leaving IE7 and IE8 not do the animate and be happy with just the rotation.

Comment: @JasdeepSingh - wow, this showed up at the top of my list of questions today because it was recently edited and I never even noticed.....my face is red. :S

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

http://jsfiddle.net/zmpdS/103/

```
$(window).load(function() {

    $("#test").rotate({
        angle: 0,
        animateTo:180,
        callback: function(){   
            $("#test").animate({
                height: "128px",
                width: "128px"
            }, 1000);
        }
     })

});
```

Comment: Thanks Wasim, but I wanted to have both `.animate()` and `.rotate()` run simultaneously.. Right now it works great on all other browsers except IE